# Открытие фото из вопросов / ответов в модальном окне

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Иногда задающий/отвечающий для демонстрации ошибок или показа порядка действий и прочего вставляют фото в свои тексты (<kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd> или нажав кнопку на панели).

Но иногда получается так, что во вставленном изображении не всегда всё видно. Какие либо надписи или значки сложно разглядеть. К примеру вот изображение ссылкой: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JubwS.png - разглядит детали даже слепой, а вот оно же при вставке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]]

Приходится вглядываться.

Да, можно нажать на него и перейти на страницу картинки, но (!) иногда в результате написания можно случайно (по незнанию, например) отрезать от этого сниппета некоторые части и тогда в другом окне просто не откроется (как я это сейчас намеренно сделал с изображением выше), а также не очень комфортно смотреть на фото, потом возвращаться обратно к вопросу или открывать в новой вкладке.

Пример: [После загрузки страницы ошибка NetworkError](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517716/191482) - если кто-то разберет что там на картинках - можно давать награду))

Еще пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498568/191482 - обратите внимание на пункт где три фото в ряд. Что-то видно? Сомневаюсь. Хотя когда делал, думал, что всё будет ок. Приходится открывать в другой вкладке либо в этой же и переходить потом обратно. Другие фото на каком-либо лаптопе слабо будут видны, в принципе сами по себе. К тому же, **важно(!)**, что люди в большинстве не предоставляют изображение в FULLHD (как я :-) ), а наоборот, побыстрее что-то наляпают и вставят, что рассмотр в более крупном варианте просто неизбежен.

Может быть стоит прикрутить открытие фото в модальном окне при клике на фото, и, если фото не одно - возможность их пролистать в модалке? Банальный `lightbox` или `fancybox` или что-то еще простое, но удобное.

**p.s.** просто поясню точнее: предложение заключается не в замене кода или кодов ошибок скриншотами и тем более бOльшими в размерах, а в том, что если вдруг присутствуют изображения в вопросах и ответах, которые прикладывают пользователи, то лучше иметь возможность их открыть в бОльшем размере (мало ли по какой причине не видно на них что-то: плохое качество или юзер подслепенький и т.д.) и иметь возможность их просмотреть подряд, как у последовательной инструкции действий (например инструкция установки `lamp`)

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста несколько примеров, когда это действительно необходимо и не решается копированием текста или вырезанием фрагмента.

Comment: Как раз хотел что-то подобное сегодня дописать. ^^^

Comment: В данном примере первая картинка ок, вторая лишняя, треться склеена из трех(?). Не вижу каким образом это иллюстрирует актуальность проблемы.

Comment: @KromStern актуальность в том, что лучше иметь возможность открыть   фото в большем размере в том же окне, если какие-то проблемы с его просмотром, нежели не иметь

Comment: "Вы читать умеете? не?" - К чему все эти условности, давайте сразу на личности перейдем и оскорбления? )))

Comment: @KromStern вы просто не понимаете суть, как мне кажется. Отсюда, кстати, 1 и 3 пункт в вашем ответе. Ибо предложение не заменить код или коды ошибок скриншотами и тем более бOльшими в размерах, а в том, что если вдруг присутствуют изображения в вопросах и ответах, которые прикладывают пользователи, то лучше иметь возможность их открыть в бОльшем размере (мало ли по какой причине не видно на них что-то) и возможность их просмотреть подряд, как  у последовательной инструкции действий, к примеру. вот и всё

Answer (score 7):

Не надо так делать.

Если вся настолько важная информация может быть представлена только в виде full-HD скриншота, то ее нельзя будет потом найти в Яндексе/Гугле/SO.

Не может быть, что для вопроса важны все 1300*800+ пикселей, что там, простыня текста? Так лучше ее скопировать и вставить. Пример ошибки рендера - покажите фрагмент. Ошибка верстки на 1 пиксель - вырежьте и покажите фрагмент.

Настоящего размера изображений вполне достаточно. Будучи принятым, это предложение поощрит вставку полных скриншотов, что ухудшит качество вопросов.

Comment: Вы увидели скриншот об ошибке и начали мыслить в узких рамках. Мыслите шире. На скринах может быть определены действия, которые юзер делал/должен сделать  для достижения результата, Т.к. новички не всегда знают где что находится, помимо текстового описания приходится подкреплять это графически. Пример в вопрос добавил. И да, для вопроса важны все 1300*800 потому, что не все фигачат скрины в кинотеатром разрешении, а просто на скорую руку сделают и вставят (например вопрошающие), что для рассмотрения нужно отдельно рассматривать.

Comment: Если бы все задумывались о качестве, то не только скринов плохого качества не было бы (в большинстве своем от новичков), но и вопросов в стиле `2x+2=0` чему равен `x`. Это просто неизбежно. Вы можете каждому из сотен-тысяч новичков лично объяснять как лучше писать вопросы и какие скрины необходимо делать и вставлять))) `ухудшит качество вопросов` - есть проверка, в которой могут спокойно что-то отклонить или написать - о том, чтобы что-то поправили.