# Картинки-ссылки на Stack Overflow

Tags: предложение, ссылки

Иногда становится необходимым открывать изображения в полном размере, чтобы разглядеть их.

[image: Плохо видимое изображение]

- Если добавляю в сообщение изображение при помощи <kbd>Сtrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> в веб-интерфейсе, то при клике левой кнопкой мыши картинка открывается, но в той же вкладке, — [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497239/199934) — и приходится нажимать на среднюю кнопку мыши.

Удобнее, когда ссылкам по умолчанию задаётся `target="_blank"`, как это реализовано, к примеру, на GitHub ([пример](https://github.com/tosher/Mediawiker/issues/65#issuecomment-213661358)).

- Длинные тексты я пишу в Sublime Text 3, поскольку в веб-интерфейсе не хватает многих полезных функций. Картинки добавляю обычной конструкцией синтаксиса Markdown: `![]()`. Но тогда изображения совсем не оборачиваются в тег `<a>`, — [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/515714/199934) — а хотелось бы иначе, как на том же GitHub.

[См. также](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2830/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5). Спасибо.

Comment: И в чем ваше предложение?

Comment: @NickVolynkin — чтобы производилось автоматическое оборачивание любых вставленных в вопрос или ответ картинок в тег `<a>` и чтобы этим ссылкам-картинкам задавалось `target="_blank"`.

Comment: и чтобы они открывались в новой вкладке?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, при клике на них левой кнопкой мыши.

Answer (score 7):

За `target=_blank` я бы расстреливал на месте. Если пользователь хочет открыть что-то в отдельной вкладке, то для этого существуют средняя кнопка мыши, контектное меню, жесты мыши, сочетания клавиш и другие средства **на стороне клиента**. Если же я хочу открыть ссылку с `target=_blank` в той же вкладке, то получается, что **сервер решает за меня**, потому что половина из очевидных способов открытия ссылки не работает как мне надо, кроме того я не могу угадать, что на ссылке висит этот архаичный атрибут. Попапы в 95% случаев — это тоже ископаемое средство, потому что почти всегда достаточно оверлея (исключения только для костылей с OpenID).

Так что пора учиться пользоваться браузером.

Впрочем, я не против, если сделают как на некоторых имадж-бордах: можно тыкнуть на какую-то часть картинки с иконкой лупы, тогда открывается оверлей на той же странице. Но не попап и не отдельное окно!

P. S. На гитхабе по вашей ссылке никаких `target=_blank` не заметил.

P. P. S. Для картинок-ссылок печальный синтаксис: `[![](url)](url)`/`[![][ref]][ref]`. За столько времени существования markdown могли бы придумать синтаксис получше...

Comment: Кому вообще нужны картинки-ссылки?

Comment: @Qwertiy Если картинка больше ширины сообщения, то имеет смысл вставить в сообщение превьюшку и сослаться на полную версию. Можно использовать и одну картинку для обеих целей.

Comment: Движок сделает это сам ведь. С какой целью именно картинку оборачивать в ссылку?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не замечал, чтобы движок делал это автоматически.

Comment: Да, похоже я неправ. Просто вставляется автоматически второй вариант.